# Concatenation of rows where first item match

Tags: r

Let's say I have a file with two columns labeled A and B. Each column consists of different strings, with repetition allowed. The A column is already sorted.
Here is an example:

```
A       B
c1045   GO:0003735
c1045   GO:0005829
c1045   GO:0005840
c1045   GO:0006412
c1045   GO:0019843
c11467  GO:0003735
c11467  GO:0005840
c11467  GO:0006412
c1168   GO:0006950
c1168   GO:0006950
c1175   GO:0003674
c1175   GO:0003729
c1175   GO:0003735
c1175   GO:0006412
```

I want to create a new file where each string in the A column will appear only once with the corresponding strings concatenated in the B column.

The resulting file will begin with:

```
A       B
c1045   GO:0003735,GO:0005829,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0019843.
c11467  GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412.
```

Is there an easy way to do so in R ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have the good keyword: aggregate and not concatenate...

Comment: `aggregate(B ~ A, data=dat, paste, sep=",")`

Comment: Good, that makes the trick !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
##
R> dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x) {
    paste0(x,collapse=",")
  }),by=A]
        A                                                      B
1:  c1045 GO:0003735,GO:0005829,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0019843
2: c11467                       GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412
3:  c1168                                  GO:0006950,GO:0006950
4:  c1175            GO:0003674,GO:0003729,GO:0003735,GO:0006412
```

---

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(
  text="A       B
c1045   GO:0003735
c1045   GO:0005829
c1045   GO:0005840
c1045   GO:0006412
c1045   GO:0019843
c11467  GO:0003735
c11467  GO:0005840
c11467  GO:0006412
c1168   GO:0006950
c1168   GO:0006950
c1175   GO:0003674
c1175   GO:0003729
c1175   GO:0003735
c1175   GO:0006412",
  header=TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Looks like it ! I upvote for now and will only accept tomorrow because I can't test right now...

Comment: Good. Bonus point : it made me learn how to install a R package. I upvote !